# Add Azure AD directory member as global administrator of B2C directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a company Azure AD which is synced with our on premise AD.

I have created a separate Azure AD B2C directory via the Azure portal, for which my Azure AD user account was automatically added as an 'External Azure Active Directory' member and a global administrator.

I can switch between the two directories by clicking on my profile when signed in to the Azure portal.

I want to add a second user from our Azure AD directory to the B2C directory to act as a global administrator, so they can sign in to the portal and switch between directories and administer the B2C directory.

Previously it was possible to do this via the Classic Azure portal.

How is this achieved in the new portal?

(I have tried inviting the user from the Azure AD directory as a guest and assigning as a Global Admin, however the user receives an error about not being a Global Admin when trying to view the B2C directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there can be quite a delay in assigning the Global Administrator directory role.

After 2 hours the user added using the following process can access the B2C directory as a global administrator:

1. Add user to the B2C directory via 'New guest user'
2. Invite a user using the email address from company Azure AD
3. Assign the guest user to the 'Global Administrator' directory role for the B2C directory

Comment: Yes, you got it.